# Cannot block port 389

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, port, windows-firewall

I have been trying to completely shut down port 389 on windows firewall. I went into the firewall and added a rule stating to block ALL connections for TCP and UDP for the port 389(Inbound and Outbound)

But it still seems to be listening and using this port.

I have multiple IP's using this server.

Comment: The software listening on 389 won't stop listening just because you've blocked inbound traffic on the firewall. It just means that you won't be able to reach it from outside that system.

Answer (score 0):

For blocking rules make sure to

- select all Domain, Private and Public under Advanced > Profiles
- keep Remote port to "All Ports" for Inbound rules
- keep Local port to "All Ports" for Outbound rules

As @RyanBolger mentioned listeners aren't affected by this but you can easily check actual connectivity by launching powershell on a different computer:

```
Test-NetConnection 192.168.1.1 -Port 389
...
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

If TcpTestSucceeded shows false, you're fine.